# How to get all results from mysql query without gouping

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I would like to know why doesn't my query give me all the results from all the joined tables without using group by. Right now, i'm getting only one result when not specifying the group by clause even though there should be thousands.

Here's the query in question

```
SELECT term_relation.term_taxonomy_id, term_relation.object_id, term_tax.taxonomy, 
term_tax.term_id, terms.name, COUNT(term_tax.term_id) as count
FROM `wp_term_relationships` as term_relation
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS term_tax USING(term_taxonomy_id)
INNER JOIN wp_terms AS terms USING(term_id)
WHERE term_relation.object_id IN (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type IN 
('product','product_variation'))
AND term_tax.taxonomy IN (SELECT concat('pa_', attribute_name) AS taxonomy
FROM wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies);
```

> (( Your SQL query has been executed successfully. With only one result
> though ))

If i would specify GROUP BY at the end of the query either by term_id or object_id i get somewhat better results but still not all that i need.

> GROUP BY term_id gives me: Showing rows 0 - 24 (11463 total, Query
> took 0.0001 seconds.)
>
> GROUP BY object_id gives me:  Showing rows 0 - 24 (92951 total, Query
> took 0.8672 seconds.)

When doing these queries sperately, i get:

```
SELECT term_relation.term_taxonomy_id, term_relation.object_id, term_tax.taxonomy, 
term_tax.term_id, terms.name, COUNT(term_tax.term_id) as count
FROM `wp_term_relationships` as term_relation
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS term_tax USING(term_taxonomy_id)
INNER JOIN wp_terms AS terms USING(term_id)
```

> (( Your SQL query has been executed successfully. Only one record
> aswell ))

```
SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type IN ('product','product_variation')
```

> Showing rows 0 - 24 (110051 total, Query took 0.0006 seconds.)

```
SELECT concat('pa_', attribute_name) AS taxonomy FROM wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies
```

> Showing rows 0 - 24 (174 total, Query took 0.0003 seconds.)

What i'm trying to build is a seperate index table for product filters since there are 100s of thousands of products and 100s of terms.

Actually this index table worked before but before i had specific object_id's and specific taxonomy terms in WHERE clauses and this got me like 700k+ records total.

What i'm trying to understand is why isn't my query working? What am i doing wrong and how could i change the query so that i would get all the records i need. Which means all the attribute terms for all the products?

Comment: You use aggregate function COUNT() - so GROUP BY is performed anycase. If you do not specify it explicitly then the whole rowset is treated as one group.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense but how could i keep the count without it performing GROUP BY? Since i need the count of term_id's

Comment: Aggregate wp_term_taxonomy in subquery then join it to another tables.

Comment: @Akina Thank you, i'll try and figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [@Akina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10138734/akina)

> You use aggregate function COUNT() - so GROUP BY is performed anycase.
> If you do not specify it explicitly then the whole rowset is treated
> as one group.
> Aggregate wp_term_taxonomy in subquery then join it to another tables.

The problem was because of the COUNT function, the group by was performed anycase. So in my case to fix the problem, i edited the query so that instead of the regular count function i used a window function which is available since mysql 8+

```
SELECT term_relation.term_taxonomy_id, term_relation.object_id, 
term_tax.taxonomy, 
term_tax.term_id, terms.name, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY term_id) count
FROM `wp_term_relationships` as term_relation
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS term_tax USING(term_taxonomy_id)
INNER JOIN wp_terms AS terms USING(term_id)
WHERE term_relation.object_id IN (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type IN 
('product','product_variation'))
AND term_tax.taxonomy IN (SELECT concat('pa_', attribute_name) AS taxonomy
FROM wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies);
```